# PL/SQL compilation error, can't figure out whats broken

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So my SQL procedure is following:

```
create or replace procedure generate_sample_dd_contracts(cnt in pls_integer)
is
begin
  for cur in (select * from (select * from tc_client cli where not exists (select 1 from tc_direct_debit dd where dd.cli_id=cli.id) order by dbms_random.value) where rownum < dbms_random.value(2,100))
    -- select query works fine and gets clients as needed
    loop
      for i in 0..cnt
        loop
          insert into tc_direct_debit (cli_id, ref_number) values (cur.id, tc_ref_num_seq.nextval);
          -- this insert also works separately from procedure, I have autoinc trigger
        end loop;
      end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
begin
  generate_sample_dd_contracts(3);
end;
```

First for loops select query result
[image]

Also when I run the procedure tc_direct_debit ID gets updated (into clause) but no data appears in table.

And the error report:

```
PROCEDURE GENERATE_SAMPLE_DD_CONTRACTS compiled
Error starting at line 19 in command:
begin
  generate_sample_dd_contracts(3);
end;
Error report:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (T.U_DIRECT_DEBIT_CLI_ID) violated
ORA-06512: at "T.GENERATE_SAMPLE_DD_CONTRACTS", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 2
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

From this I understand that insert tries to add a cli_id that already exists but tc_direct_debit is empty (have truncated it many times to be sure).

tc_direct_debit table

```
`CREATE TABLE TC_DIRECT_DEBIT
(ID NUMBER NOT NULL
, CLI_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, REF_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT TC_DIRECT_DEBIT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
, CONSTRAINT U_DIRECT_DEBIT_CLI_ID UNIQUE (CLI_ID)
, CONSTRAINT TC_DIRECT_DEBIT_CLI_FK FOREIGN KEY (CLI_ID) REFERENCES TC_CLIENT (ID)
);`
```

Comment: Does the table `tc_direct_debit` contains `cli_id` as a primary key ?

Comment: No it does not, added it to post.

Comment: But it has unique constraint on it `CONSTRAINT U_DIRECT_DEBIT_CLI_ID UNIQUE (CLI_ID)`

Comment: and what is this extra loop? `for i in 0..cnt` you are trying to insert the same `cli_id` for `cnt` times

Comment: It was meant to add cnt different direct debits per client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every line in the cursor you insert it four times (from 0 to three).

A code doing what I think you want to do is:

```
create or replace procedure generate_sample_dd_contracts(cnt in pls_integer)
is
declare 
i number;
begin
i:=0;
  for cur in (select * from (select * from tc_client cli where not exists (select 1 from tc_direct_debit dd where dd.cli_id=cli.id) order by dbms_random.value) where rownum < dbms_random.value(2,100))
    loop
      i:=i+1;
      exit when i > cnt;
      insert into tc_direct_debit (cli_id, ref_number) values (cur.id, tc_ref_num_seq.nextval);
    end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

Or better, just changing the cursor code:

```
create or replace procedure generate_sample_dd_contracts(cnt in pls_integer)
is
begin
  for cur in (select * from (select * from tc_client cli where not exists (select 1 from tc_direct_debit dd where dd.cli_id=cli.id) order by dbms_random.value) where rownum <= cnt)
    loop
      insert into tc_direct_debit (cli_id, ref_number) values (cur.id, tc_ref_num_seq.nextval);
    end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: This is also one possible interpretation of the task. I actually went with this since I'm not allowed to change table definiton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `CLI_ID` is mentioned as `unique key` which means the dulicate will not accepted at any cost. wherears in the procedure `line 9` has looped insert

```
 for i in 0..cnt
   loop
     insert into tc_direct_debit (cli_id, ref_number) values (cur.id, tc_ref_num_seq.nextval);
   -- this insert also works separately from procedure, I have autoinc trigger
 end loop;
```

removing the unique contraint `U_DIRECT_DEBIT_CLI_ID` will resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you! I'm preparing for SQL exam and it was a part of a task which stated that procedure is supposed to generate cnt direct debit contracts for random clients who already don’t have one but task statement seems to be in conflict with TC_DIRECT_DEBIT table definition then.